# ReactiveTabbedPage set child view to navigate to

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I am using ReactiveTabbedPage 'HomeTabbedPage' which has 4 view as shown

```
<rxui:ReactiveTabbedPage x:Class="HomeTabbedPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:rxui="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI.XamForms;assembly=ReactiveUI.XamForms"
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MeasuringPoint.Views;assembly=MeasuringPoint"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MeasuringPoint.Controls;assembly=MeasuringPoint"
xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:MeasuringPoint.Resources;assembly=MeasuringPoint"
xmlns:page="clr-namespace:MeasuringPoint.Pages"
xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:MeasuringPoint.ViewModels"
x:TypeArguments="vms:HomeTabbedViewModel" BackgroundColor="White">

<views:CreateView x:Name="createView" Title="Create"/>
<views:HistoryView x:Name="historyView" Title="History"/>
<views:SyncView x:Name="syncView" Title="Sync"/>
<views:SettingsView x:Name="settingsView" Title="Settings" />  
</rxui:ReactiveTabbedPage>
```

By default Createview is the one shown. I need to navigate to another 'Page' and come back to another child view 'SettingsView'

If I call

```
HostScreen
            .Router
            .Navigate
            .Execute(new SettingsViewModel())
            .Subscribe();
```

The SettingsView is displayed but the tabs disappear.

If I can navigate back to the HomeTabbedPage

```
HostScreen
            .Router
            .Navigate
            .Execute(new HomeTabbedViewModel())
            .Subscribe();
```

Then the CreateView is displayed.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think you shouldn't use ReactiveUI's Navigation here.

Comment: Can you expand on your comment?

Comment: Forget my previous commet I just noticed you are using *Navigate* to _NavigateBack_ but it isn't the case, to _NavigateBack_you should use *NavigateBack* command from Router class.

Comment: NavigationBack works in this instance, however if you'd like to land on a different child view of the tabbed page that wasn't accessed last, won't work.